# How to update object hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem with update object from java code to postgresql.
When I'm updating object, I'm having a problem with id, because id is null. Thus in database is creating a new row instead of overwriting the same row.
It seems like, the row in database:

```
id = 1
name = "name"
then I'm sending a json, like:
{
  name: "newName"
}
```

then I'm getting the new row and it seems:

```
id = 1, name = "name"
id = 2, name = "newName"
```

It's because when I'm sending a json there id is null, so postgresql is creating a new row, but I want to overwrite the row with `id = 1`. One of solution to add in `@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)`, but I don't like it, because it deleting the old id then creating the new id. How do I can overwrite the initial row if I don't have id?

Thanks!

```
class A{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
UUID id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "A", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
B b;
}

class B{
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "A_id")
A a;
}

updatedA.setInfo(jsonSend.getInfo());
```

Comment: The key to any solution to this problem is that you need to tell the database which record is being updated. You can do this by either presenting the id of the record to update, or any other field that can uniquely identify the record.

Comment: Post your code that handles the JSON (Spring MVC controller?) and attempts to save to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

between, I solved my problem with 'spring beanutils copyproperties' maybe it helps to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Send the id to the client and when it call put/post, send it back. You wouldnt know which record should be updated without that (this is the regular solution).
Other solution, if the name is unique/natural id (i dont think so), you can post the old name and the new one too. Then select the record with old name, update the object and save.

Comment: Well, I don't know id when I'm calling put/post. I just have object which one related with another table by @OneToOne. For example, I have a human {"firstName": "name",  "document": {
      "name": "passport"
    },}. Then In database I'm getting Human id=1, firstName=name, document_id=3. After I'm calling the human of database, humanRepository.findById(1). Then client is sending update, {"id"=1, "firstName": "name",  "document": {
      "name": "randomDocument"
    },}. And then I'm just getting a new row. But we know it, user by id = 1, change his document.

Comment: If it is a onetoone relationship, you just select the parent get the children and update the child's propr field, then save.

Comment: I'm doing so, but it not overwrite id, it creates a new id. if my "randomDocument" has id = 1, then if I update "randomDocument2" will get id = 2, and the human will get related to id = 2, but I want to overwrite id = 1.

Comment: can you copy your save code (and other relevants) to pastebin and link it here?

Comment: the problem is you set a new datadocument to your entity
human.setDocumentData(updateHuman.getDocumentData());|

you should get the document:
DocumentData dd=human.setDocumentData()
then set the proper fields dd.setName(YourNewName)

in most cases, mappers like mapstruct, etc is better choice than do it manually

Comment: yeah, alright. But I'cant understand how would mapper could to help. I can exclude "id", but overwrite. Could you give some tips, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CrudRepository.
Well some part of code, entities:

```
  public class Human {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  @Column(name = "first_name")
  String firstName;

  @Column(name = "last_name")
  String lastName;

  @JoinColumn(name = "data_document_id")
  @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  DataDocument dataDocument;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "human", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Singular
  List<Book> books;

}



  public class DataDocument {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;

  String name;
 }



public class Book {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;

  Boolean isReaded;

  Integer type;

  Integer cost;

  Instant date;
}
```

Here I make POST to create a human:

```
{
  "firstName": "firstName",
  "lastName": "lastName",
  "dataDocument": {
      "name": "randomDocument"
    },
  "books": [
    {
      "isReaded": true,
      "type": 0,
      "cost": 100,
      "date": "2019-06-11"
    }
  ]
}


humanRepository.save(human);
```

So it's ok, I'm having to get the row in database:

```
TABLE HUMAN
human_id = 1, firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName, data_document_id = 1

TABLE DOCUMENT_DATA
data_document_id = 1, name = randomDocument

TABLE BOOK
book_id = 1, human_id = 1, type = 0, cost = 100, date = "2019-06-11", isReaded = true
```

Then I want to update my the human. For example json:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "firstName",
  "lastName": "lastName",
  "dataDocument": {
      "name": "NEW_DOCUMENT"
    },
  "books": [
    {
      "isReaded": true,
      "type": 0,
      "cost": 100,
      "date": "2019-06-11"
    }
  ]
}
```

My method:

```
  public Human updateHuman(Long humanId, updateHuman){
    Human human = humanRepository.findById(humanId);
    human.setDocumentData(updateHuman.getDocumentData());
    humanRepository.save(human);
  }
```

Then in the table, I will get:

```
TABLE HUMAN
human_id = 1, firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName, data_document_id = 2

TABLE DOCUMENT_DATA
data_document_id = 1, name = randomDocument
data_document_id = 2, name = NEW_DOCUMENT
```

That's the problem. I want to overwrite data_document_id = 1 to new name. I know some solutions like

```
 @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)
```

but it would gives the next result:

```
TABLE DOCUMENT_DATA
data_document_id = 2, name = NEW_DOCUMENT
```

Also I'd can to write code like this:

```
  public Human updateHuman(Long humanId, updateHuman){
    Human human = humanRepository.findById(humanId);
    Long id = human.getDocumentData().getId();
    human.setDocumentData(updateHuman.getDocumentData());
    human.getDocumentData().setId(id);
    humanRepository.save(human);
  }
```

Then it's would work fine. But I have like 40 fields and 10 of them Lists and 10 of them another entities with too many fields.
I just want to find the easiest way how I can update the object. I thought about query, but I'm not sure if it will work.
Just I have a HUMAN to UPDATED_SOME_FIELDS = HUMAN_WITH_UPDATED_SOME_FIELDS.